# Declaring multiple variables on one line out of order

Tags: java

I recently saw this in some Java code:

```
int pos = -1, ch;
```

Is that the same as

```
int pos, ch = -1;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the first code snippet only initializes `pos` with `-1` and leaves `ch` uninitialized. The second one does it the other way round leaving `pos` uninitialized and `ch` with the value `-1`. But in either case, both `ch` and `pos` will be created and you will be able to set or update their values.

Answer (score 1):

i would say yes...the only difference being what you are initializing (in first statement you assigned value to first variable and other left untouched so only first variable is initialize to value and other just remain a reference variable of type int) the same is true for Second statement...

if you say :

```
int x=10,y;
```

here x is initialized to value 10 and y to default **(ie 0 but compiler will throw compilation error "variable y might not have been initialized!" )**

but if you say

```
int x,y=10;
```

then x is set to default **(ie 0 again compilation will throw compilation error variable x not initialized !)** and y is set to value 10

what does not matter here is the order of occurrence for x and y.. hope that clarifies! :D

Comment: You can't say "yes, they are the same" when you then go on to explain how they are not the same.

Comment: i am not sure what you are pointing out for because i tried explaining why i said yes...

Comment: You said yes and then explained why the answer is no, since they are not the same.

Comment: clearly the user pointed two statements and asked "are those same" so its obvious to say "no" as they are two statement but, i took the programming context why they are same..(how you can declare variables) anyways the user already have their ans...so thanks for pointing that point to me..:D

Comment: It's still not proper. If it was initialized to zero why would the compiler throw an error? And you're still saying yes even though they are not the same as you explain. Why not just say "no, they are not the same because..."?

Answer (score 0):

In both lines two variables are being created. In the first one only `pos` is initialized with -1 and in the second one only `ch` is initialized with -1. Before you use the uninitialized ones, some values should be assigned to them.